# how to center the title in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
 # Label
        self.intro_label = Label(self, text = 'Currency Convertor', fg = '#1C1075', relief = tk.RAISED, borderwidth = 3)
        self.intro_label.config(font = ('Courier',15,'bold'))

        self.date_label = Label(self, text = f"Date : {self.currency_converter.data['date']}", relief = tk.GROOVE, borderwidth = 5)

        self.intro_label.place(x = 10 , y = 5)
        self.date_label.place(x = 160, y= 50)
```

**I would like to center the title "Currency Convertor" in the GUI.**

use the center function

Answer (score 0):

As I think you have to set label configuration configure(anchor="center")
in your case `self.intro_label.configure(anchor="center")`

Comment: This along won't guarantee that it's centered unless the calling code has done the math to insure that the arguments given to `place` are correct. Then, if the user resizes the window it will no longer be centered.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!!! And i got another issue with my code, if I want to add a time section, how can I do this? right now the current code only contain date instead of both date and time. Hope you can help me with that! thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use `pack` or `grid`, but you can do it with `place` by using relative positioning. Using `relx` instead of `x` lets you add it to a relative position, and it will stay in that relative position even when the window is resized. `relx` takes a floating point value between 0 and 1, with .5 being the center.

You also need to make sure you use the `anchor` attribute to make sure the top center of the label is at the relative coordinate.

```
self.intro_label.place(relx = .5 , y = 5, anchor="n")
```

Comment: And i got another issue with my code, if I want to add a time section, how can I do this? right now the current code only contain date instead of both date and time. Hope you can help me with that! thanks!!!!